# Multiple instances of provider in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I created an Angular 2 library for work that helps with creating workflows/state machines. My issue is that I cannot create multiple instances of WorkflowService` foe each workflow in my application.

It is encapsulated in its own module that the consumer can `import` into their `ngModule` like so:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    WorkflowModule.forWorkflow({
      name: 'Turnstile',
      initialStage: 'Locked',
      transitions: [
        {
          name: 'Coin',
          from: ['Locked', 'Unlocked'],
          to: 'Unlocked',
        },
        {
          name: 'Push',
          from: 'Unlocked',
          to: 'Locked'
        }
      ]
    })
  ],
  exports: [WorkflowModule]
})
export class TurnstileWorkflowModule {}
```

Internally, the `forWorkflow` method looks like this:

```
static forWorkflow(config: WorkflowConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: WorkflowModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: WORKFLOW_CONFIG, useValue: config },
        { provide: WorkflowService, useClass: WorkflowService },
      ]
    };
  }
```

The issue with this current setup is that it doesn't allow me to have multiple instances of the `WorkflowService`. How can I reconfigure this to have multiple instance for each consumer?

Thanks!

---

UPDATE: 
Thanks to @jonrsharpe for the help. I've updated the code but now my application won't compile with AOT.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
export class WorkflowProvider {
  public static forWorkflow(config: WorkflowConfig): Provider {
    return {
      provide: WorkflowService,
      useValue: workflowFactory(config),
      deps: [Injector]
    };
  }
}
```

the factory:

```
export function workflowFactory(config: WorkflowConfig) {
  return function (injector: Injector) {
    return new WorkflowEngine(config, injector);
  };
}
```

The error that I'm receiving:

> ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 9:10 in the
>   original .ts file), resolving symbol workflowFactory

Comment: Have you read https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#multiple-service-instances-sandboxing?

Comment: Yes, but I still don't know how to get the above to work correctly. I would like the configuration for each workflow to create an independent instance

Comment: Have you? Because you're including it as a provider in a `ModuleWithProviders`, which is basically the opposite of what you want; that creates an application-wide singleton. Instead provide it at the component level, per the docs.

Comment: Thank you. I reconfigured the above to not use `ModuleWithProviders` but instead I define the provider directly into the component and it works. Is there any way to move the provider definition into the module itself as opposed to the component?